# How do I check if my root password (login) is disabled?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I accidentally enabled(set) my root password (by default it is locked), and now I want to "undo" it.
I used both commands

```
sudo usermod -p '!' root
```

and

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

in that order.

How do I check if root's account is locked?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `passwd` command:

```
# passwd -S
root P 11/04/2014 -1 -1 -1 -1
# passwd -l root
passwd: password expiry information changed.
# passwd -S 
root L 11/04/2014 -1 -1 -1 -1
# passwd -d root
passwd: password expiry information changed.
# passwd -S 
root NP 11/04/2014 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

From [`man 1 passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/passwd.1):

```
   -S, --status
       Display account status information. The status information consists
       of 7 fields. The first field is the user's login name. The second
       field indicates if the user account has a locked password (L), has
       no password (NP), or has a usable password (P). The third field
       gives the date of the last password change. The next four fields
       are the minimum age, maximum age, warning period, and inactivity
       period for the password. These ages are expressed in days.
```

The data shown is stored in [`/etc/shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shadow.5), the file which holds the encrypted passwords.

For example, after each of the above `passwd` commands, the states were:

```
1:root:$6$............long hash...............::::::
1:root:!$6$........same long hash.............:16478::::::
1:root::16478::::::
```

Comment: What does a locked password mean?

Comment: @QuintenCabo that the password is still there but you're not able to use it for logging in

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is to look into /etc/passwd by entering

```
grep root /etc/passwd
```

It should show a line starting like `root:x: ......` where the x indicates that encrypted passwords are stored in the shadow file. If this is the case, we look into it by running

```
sudo grep root /etc/shadow
```

(shadow file needs sudo to be opened!) You should get a line beginning like the following as a result `root:!: ......` where the `!` or a `*` signalize that the account is disabled. Any other value (not beginning with ! or *) after `root:` would indicate a working password.

Comment: thank you, but I'm just wondering, is there any file that contains that information?

Comment: I researched a bit and added another part to my answer, accessing the files where the passwords are stored, just as you wished.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion, and it is wrong, sudo still uses user password.
 Edited paragraph works, that is information I was looking for

Comment: source of the data is 
`man passwd.5`
and `man shadow.5`

Answer (score 0):

By default when you install Ubuntu you should not know root password. It exists, but user should not know it. An admin, of course, could choose to alter the password with `sudo passwd` but generally it should not be necessary, unless you know what you're doing and why you're doing it.

A file that contains information on all user passwords is `/etc/shadow`  and each entry in that file is encrypted. So unless an attacker gained access to your system and stole this file, he or she should not be able to enter root at all. There's always a possibility, of course, hence I suggest you disable any remote access features : telnet (not enabled by default ) , ssh, remote desktop, etc. Get yourself `nmap` tool and scan your system with `sudo nmap localhost` to see what ports may be open on your system. Also, get yourself a firewall; ubuntu comes with ufw firewall, which is simple to use and does the job well enough.

Among other methods, you could test root account with `sudo -i`

In the `/etc/sudoers` file , you should have a line like this : `sudo -i`. If you can't log in as root, you do not see the # as prompt, then the account is locked

`Defaults   env_reset,timestamp_timeout=30`

timestamp_timeout will tell sudo to ask for password after 30 seconds again, so that you aren't logged in with root privileges all the time. It's one of the ways of securing your system.

An adverse side effect of changing root password is that if you forget password or another user on your system forgets the password, you won't have access to root. I'm not aware of any instances, but there's always possibility to mess up the system, because some of the processes run as root, and if you lock root account there is a possibility those might not work correctly or at all.

I strongly recommend you read through `man sudoers` , `man passwd,`man shadow`.

Best of luck and hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

## catch bleow one liner command for password report of all existed users in linux sever.

```
for i in $(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'); do echo "##############" "$i" "############";chage -l $i; echo "##################################"; done | nl | less
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy.

Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1. This will bring to a separate terminal. Try to login as root by typing `root` as your login and providing the password.

If the root account is enabled, the login will work. If the root account is disabled, the login will fail.

To get back to your GUI, hit Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: You don't need to go all the way to the TTY for that. A simple `su` will do.

Comment: thank you, I tried and now it is locked.


But I wonder is there any file that I can open and check it.

Let's say hypothetically I can't remember password that I typed, and there is no option to set another one with sudo from user, so I want to check some login file if it exists.